# Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' -database error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
public function count_category_images($p_id)
{
$this->db->select('gallery.*','category.category_name');
$this->db->join('category', 'category.id = gallery.category_id');
$this->db->order_by('gallery.id','desc');
$this->db->where('category.id',$p_id); 

return $this->db->count_all_results('gallery');//line no 81
}
```

am getting this error

> Error Number: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause'

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM
    `gallery`
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `gallery`.`category_id`
WHERE
    `category`.`id` = `Array`
ORDER BY
    `gallery`.`id` DESC
```

**Filename: C:/wamp64/www/rox/application/models/roxmodel.php**

Line Number: 81

Comment: your $p_id is an array i guess.Before pass the $p_id just echo and test the value for $p_id

Comment: is your category.id an 'Array' ??

Comment: that is what i already ask you @MOHAMMED

Comment: if $p_id is array means use $this->db->where_in('category.id', $p_id);

Comment: and also missing $this->db->from('gallery');

Comment: @jothi count_all_results does that.

Comment: okay okay   @smozgur

Answer (score 0):

Your **$p_id** is an array i guess.Before pass the **$p_id** just echo and test the value for **$p_id**

In your where clause you **`category`.`id`** should equal some value not an array.

Answer (score 0):

You need "where_in" instead of existing "where". I think codeigniter works like below:

```
$this->db->where_in('category.id',$p_id);
```

EDIT: More specific: where_in will create following according to your parameter, model and intention as I can see:

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) AS `numrows`
FROM `gallery`
JOIN `category` ON `category`.`id` = `gallery`.`category_id`
WHERE `category`.`id` IN ('1', '2', '3')
ORDER BY `gallery`.`id` DESC
```

Comment: the values is not getting in to the array

Comment: @MOHAMMED use print_r($p_id) to see what it prints, then paste here so we and you know what it is.

Comment: am getting print_r($p_id) as Array

Comment: @MOHAMMED do this: - public function count_category_images($p_id) { print_r($p_id); exit; }

Comment: am getting corresponding id value